# Place div with one element next to div with many elements and when resizing window put element one under another

Tags: html, css

I have following situation (look for the image below)
[image: Image 1]

I want the button which is alone to be on the left, rest of the buttons (which are inside
their own div) to be on the left. when i will resize (making window smaller) I want to achieve 
what is in the first resizing (one button goes down), and then on the second resizing two buttons below
and then 4 buttons in column at the end.

I have thought about something like this in css file:

```
.aaa {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
.bbb {
    float: left;
}

.ccc {
    float: left;
}
```

but after first resizing only button with className="bbb" stays in this row,
and Button1,2 and 3 goes below the first one, so its like:
[image]

Comment: I don't think what  you are trying to do is easily done without absolute positioning elements or using JS. Why do the 3 buttons need to be in a separate div?

Comment: ok, doesn't matter, i found solution

Comment: Awesome, well feel free to submit an answer to your question with your solution and accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `display: flex`, but it won't result in exactly what you want.

See below example:

```css
.aaa {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.bbb {
  flex: 0;
}



.ccc {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">
  <button class="bbb">Button</button>
  <div class="ccc">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did something like this (and this is just enough for me):

```
.aaa {
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.bbb {
    float: left;
}
```

So completely ignoring the "ccc" class.